# how do I keep a division from being visible behind another division when the other division is in an absolute position?

Tags: html, css, positioning, absolute, scrollbars

I'm really going to try and ask this as clearly as I can.  I'm not even sure it's possible, but that's why I'm here!

I'm writing an HTML page that has five divisions on it:

The first is a container division ("content") that contains two divisions in it ("mainsection" and "textnav").  There is a graphical navigation division ("graphnav") that has a small copyright division ("copy") but I don't have the problem with those last two.  The way the page is laid out, I have the "textnav" and "graphnav" divisions fixed to the bottom of the page using position: fixed; bottom (with the pixel position) but I want "mainsection" division to be vertically flexible and to show scroll bars when the content exceeds the vertical size of the "mainsection" division.

Now from what I understand, I can attach overflow-y: auto to "mainsection" to take care of the scrollbars, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get "mainsection" to stay on top so to speak of the "textnav" division.  I've defined "mainsection" as having a height of "auto" but the text goes behind the "textnav" division.  It should stop on top of the "textnav" division, leaving the background  of "textnav" transparent.  The "graphnav" division has a defined pixel height, the "textnav" division does not.  Is there a way to define the height of the "mainsection" division so it doesn't encroach on the bottom divisions?

Comment: Please provide some sample code. http://jsfiddle.net/ is great

Comment: or even better, as a code snippet in your question

Comment: No problem!  I'll give the HTML first then the CSS:

Comment: <!--contains the masthead and text navigation divs-->
<div="content">

<div id="mainsection"><!--this will be the main area with overflow -->
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
<!--main graphic with CI to the right-->
</div><!--mainsection-->

<!--text navigation-->
<div id="textnav">
<hr>

<hr>
</div>

</div><!--content-->

<!--graphical navigation (graphnav) at bottom-->
<div id="graphnav">

<!--scrolling graphical menu code. Thumbnails in a table-->

<!--copyright notice at bottom right-->
<div id="copy">
</div>
</div><!--graphnav-->

Comment: That didn't come out looking right at all.  Sorry.  New to all this. :)

Comment: Here is the CSS:

body {margin: 0; background-image: url(graphics/marblebg2.png); background-color: #FFFFF; background-attachment=fixed; font-family: helvetica, arial; color: #000055}

#content {  
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 float: top;
}

#mainsection { /*part I'm having trouble with*/

 margin: 25px;
 width: 95%;
 float: top;
 height: auto;
 overflow-y: auto;
 -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
}

#textnav {
 color: #0000BB;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 102px;
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#graphnav {
 position: fixed; 
 bottom: 0; 
 height: 105px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #563E61
}

Comment: @rjdown, 
I visited jsfiddle.net, but I'm not sure what I'm looking at.  It looks...interesting.  What is it exactly?

Comment: @Lenita it lets you set up an environment where we can easily play with the code to find a solution. You just need to put your HTML in the HTML box and your CSS in the CSS box, hit save and then post the link. It's optional but really useful. But always post your code in your question.

Comment: @rjdown, thank you sir!  I'll fool around with it and see what it tells me as well.